# Find value from a table where are more articles with the same value Xpath

Tags: xpath

I need to find the value of the first article in a table where are more articles with the same value

```html
<div ng-repeat="(index, item) in vm.model.unloadingRemarksData.goodsItemRemarks" ng-class="{'odd': index%2 == 1, 'even': index%2 == 0 }" class="tr ng-scope even" model-validation-base="model.unloadingPermissionData.goodsItemRemarks" style="">
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">1</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">K_se</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">800,00 kg</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">1.000,00 kg</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">5</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">-</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">Conform</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">-</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">-</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;" title="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="(index, item) in vm.model.unloadingRemarksData.goodsItemRemarks" ng-class="{'odd': index%2 == 1, 'even': index%2 == 0 }" class="tr ng-scope odd" model-validation-base="model.unloadingPermissionData.goodsItemRemarks" style="">
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">2</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">pruimenbrandewijn</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">550,00 kg</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">600,00 kg</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">45</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">-</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">Conform</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">-</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;">-</div>
<div class="td text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" style="width: 10%;" title="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
</div>
```

When i use the Xpath:

//*[contains(@class, '') and contains(text(),'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890')][1]

I see both value

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to select for the first one, use:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'even')]/div[contains(text(),'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890')]]
```

For the other one, use:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'odd')]/div[contains(text(),'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890')]][1]
```

Comment: Don't works for both

Comment: Please, check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you it works when i use:

```html
//div[contains(@class, 'odd')]/div[contains(text(),'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890')]
```

```html
//div[contains(@class, 'even')]/div[contains(text(),'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890')]
```